# Javascript executing both if and else for string value condition

Tags: javascript

I have a one line if else that evaluates wether a string is empty `""` or `"[]"` and then if it is not, parses from json to js.

```
console.log(a === "" || a === "[]")
console.log(typeof a)
const aLength = a === "" || a === "[]" ? 0 : JSON.parse(a).length
```

however, even after double checking that it entered the if condidtion, it gives me a JSON parse error from the else block.
But the interesting thing is, when I put a console log in the else statement, I don' have any issues.

```
const aLength = a === "" || a === "[]" ? 0 : console.log('nothing') && JSON.parse(a).length
```

can anyone explain this behaviour? I tried recreating it on the console, but I couldn't.
My suspicion is that there is a wierd string type that causes both the if and else statements to execute.

**PS:**

- FYI, i'm loading the data from mongoDB.
- I also did a conventional if else and had the same issue The log for the evaluation of the if is `true`

Comment: console.log returns undefined -> ends before &&

Comment: Instead of guessing, why not check the value of `a` and actually see that it is not valid JSON?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. What value of 'a' is giving you a parse error?

Comment: @trincot I did, of course. `console.log (a) ` was empty, and `console.log(typeof a)` was` string`

Comment: If console.log(typeof a) was `string` then it may possible that you are having `blank space` like `a = " "`;

Comment: @Estradiaz rthank you that explains that part, but if the evaluation of the if condiditon was true, why did it go to the else?
Does JS execute both the if and the else, if the condition is neither true or false?

Comment: "_Javacript executing both if and else_" This is never possible. Please check your results and the executed statements.

Comment: Please be sure that the length of `a` was indeed zero. If there is any white space or other  "invisible" character there, it is normal that it gets to the `JSON.parse` bit and fails.

Comment: @toing_toing check updates in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your `a` is not an empty string `""` but contains some invisible characters like for example a BOM (byte order mark - `"\uFEFF"`) or a newline (`"\n"`).

The easiest fix is probably to `.trim()` the string before comparing it, thereby removing all whitespace at the start and the end.

Regarding the `console.log` behavior you observed, this is because `console.log` always returns `undefined`, which is falsy. Therefore, `console.log(something) && throwAnError()` will never call `throwAnError()` because the `&&` is short-circuited and the right-hand side is not executed.

Comment: In the end it was a single value in the DB that was not a string :/

Answer (score 2):

You can understand this by following example

```js
var a = console.log("nothing");
console.log("a =", a);

// a is undefined so && operator checks for first operand in this case
// its undefined this mean its evaluted into false
// && operator evalute operands until it finds a false
a && console.log("&& nothing");

// a is undefined so || operator checks for first operand in this case
// its undefined this mean its may evaluted into true so
// it goes for next operand
// || operator evalute operands until it finds a true
a || console.log("|| nothing");
```

Output

```
nothing
a = undefined
|| nothing
undefined
```

One interesting following result. Try this and paste into javascript console. It is a invisble character from [here](http://emptycharacter.com/)

```
"‎"
```

Try this also

```
var a = "Yess‎";
console.log(a);
console.log(a === "Yess");
```

Output

```
Yess‎
false
```